# Swift String Separation

Tags: arrays, swift

I am reading a file which contains data in format:

`1990    3     6.4    1.0    9`

`1991    1     5.3   12.0   10`

so the resulting array is
`["1990"][""][""][""]["3"]....`

when i only require

`["1991"]["3"]["6.4"]....`

I want to extract this information into an array or struct.
But when I try to to:

```
let x = string.components(seperatedBy: .whitespaces)
```

it creates an array with whitespaces which I do not need.

The array should only contain the values which are usefull.

Thanks

Comment: It does successfully separates the string to an array which contains no `whitespaces`. (e.g. `["1990", "3", "6.4", "1.0", "9", "1991", "1", "5.3", "12.0", "10"]`)

Comment: Sorry I think the post has removed white spaces and new line,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Converting multiple continuous whitespaces into one.

   ```
   let string = """
   1990    3     6.4    1.0    9
   1991    1     5.3   12.0   10
   """
   let components = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s+", with: " ", options: .regularExpression)
       .components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)
   ```
2. Using `Scanner`.

   ```
   let scanner = Scanner(string: string)
   var result: [String] = []
   var value: NSString? = nil
   while scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines, into: &value) {
       result.append(value as! String)
   }
   ```
3. Enumerating for words.

   ```
   var words: [String] = []
   string.enumerateSubstrings(in: string.startIndex..<string.endIndex, options: .byWords) {word, _, _, _ in
       words.append(word!)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks I used the Scanner method and it is working. Although I also found another method using extentions but this looks much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You can try splitting the values by the space character, if `.whitespaces` doesn't work for you.

```
let string = "1990 3 6.4 1.0 9 1991 1 5.3 12.0 10"
let strings = string.components(separatedBy: " ") // or .whitespaces to be more thorough
```

Furthermore, you can map the values into actual numbers.

```
let numbers = strings.flatMap(NumberFormatter().number)
```